# Prepare HttpResponseMessage to return file from Web API, not getting expected results

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, webrequest, httpresponsemessage

So, I'm stumped on something, and I have this down to the bare minimums as best I can, but complete otherwise.  I'm working in C#.  I have an C#.net WebAPI project  AND a C#.net WPF application as the client.  Its almost like the actual content of the file is never returned with the response.

On the client side, I am sending a request to a controller to get a zip file sitting on the server (my same localhost machine so I can test/debug both parts).  Here is that code

```
private static void SamplePost()
{
    var myURL = "http://localhost:52575/MySvc/GetZipFromWebAPI";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(myURL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test string");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/plain";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Now, on the WebAPI project, I have the controller and public method that does nothing but try to return a fixed-known zip file.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetZipFromWebAPI()
{
    var fileToSendBack = @"C:\Users\Public\Sample.zip";
    var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToSendBack);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var oneContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    oneContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    response.Content = oneContent;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    return response;
}
```

So, I try as simple as send the request, and return a response.  Upon the many different attempts I have sampled with, the best I had on the return was that the file size was correct (about 12k zip file), but no ZIP on the client side when I get the response.

Whatever parts I am missing / mis-understanding would be great to have resolved.  I have gone through many posts that showed one side or the other, but even working with those, not getting what I think SHOULD be simple.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is missing on the Web-API side is the Method and Parameter  Attributes
Something like

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetZipFromWebAPI([FromBody] string data)
```

Comment: Did nothing... the content return length is only showing 210 bytes when I am expecting a 12k file

Comment: 2 questions, 1. Did you verify this method is called? 2. Can you share the returned response?

Comment: I absolutely KNOW the method was called.  The response coming back had the typical stuff of OK, Content type / disposition, but the content length was only about 108 bytes (per the WebResponse properties).  I was expecting the content length of longer per the included bytes.  Almost like the bytes were never included in the return.  Again, my testing, I have BOTH applications running with debug on both... on client for send AND receive, and on the client receiving, processing and up to the returned response object.  Appreciate the follow-up too.

Comment: Try setting the content length
`response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _fileUri);
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _fileLength.ToString();`